# Peer.js remote stream returns black screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, peerjs

I was working on a simple video chat app using Peer.js and React. After calling and answering call, I notice that on both ends, the remote video stream received was not "on" and return a black screen, in spite of having set the scrObj of the video element to the stream.

```
    const vidSenderRef = useRef(null);
    const vidReceiverRef = useRef(null);
    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useContext(userContext);
    const [me, setMe] = useState(null);
    const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
    const [isCalling, setIsCalling] = useState(false);

    async function askUserMedia() {
        let stream = null;
        try {
            stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: {
                    facingMode: "user",
                }, audio: false
            })
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (err.message === "Device in use") {
                const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
                const videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.label.includes("OBS"));
                const video = videoDevices[0].deviceId;
                stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: {
                        deviceId: {
                            exact: video
                        },
                        facingMode: "user",
                    }, audio: false
                })
            }
            else {
                toastError("Error" + err.message)
            }
        }
        setStream(stream);
        vidSenderRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    }

    function assignPeer() {
        const peer = new Peer({
            host: "localhost",
            port: 9000,
            path: "/",
            secure: true,
            // debug: 3,
            config: {
                'iceServers': [
                    { url: 'stun:stun01.sipphone.com' },
                    {
                        url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
                        credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                        username: '28224511:1379330808'
                    },
                    {
                        url: 'turn:turn.bistri.com:80',
                        credential: 'homeo',
                        username: 'homeo'
                    },
                ]
            },
        })
        return peer;
    }

    async function callUser(ID) {
        const call = me.call(ID, stream);
        call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
            vidReceiverRef.current.srcObject = userVideoStream;
            console.log(userVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].getCapabilities());
            vidReceiverRef.current.play()
        });
        setIsCalling(true);
    }

    async function answerCall() {
        me.on("call", (call) => {
            call.answer(stream);
            call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
                vidReceiverRef.current.srcObject = userVideoStream;
                // vidReceiverRef.current.play();
            });
        });
        setIsCalling(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        Cookies.set("currentRoom", "00ewRc");
        Socket.emit("join", {
            sender: user.ID,
            receiver: user.ID === 1 ? 2 : 1,
        });
        askUserMedia();
        setMe(assignPeer());
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // caller side
        if (!me || !stream) return;
        if (props.caller === user.ID) {
            Socket.emit("handshake",
                {
                    caller: user.ID,
                    callee: props.callee,
                    isCallerHandshake: true,
                    room: Cookies.get("currentRoom")
                });
        }

        // callee side
        if (props.callee === user.ID && !isCalling) {
            answerCall();
        }

        Socket.on("handshake", (data) => {
            if (data.isCallerHandshake && data.callee === user.ID) {
                Socket.emit("handshake", {
                    caller: data.caller,
                    callee: user.ID,
                    isCalleeHandshake: true,
                    ID: me.id,
                    room: Cookies.get("currentRoom")
                })
            }
            else if (data.isCalleeHandshake && data.caller === user.ID && !isCalling) {
                callUser(data.ID);
            }
        })
    }, [me, stream]);

    useEffect(() => {
        vidReceiverRef.current.play();
    }, [])
```

I have tried to console log the remote stream and its track, and it returns a MediaStream object with both audio and video MediaStreamTrack, but the video stream track's capabilities only device ID and an empty facing mode array, nothing about the aspect ratio or the dimension of the stream. Then I tried to capture the event fired when setting the scrObj and only loadstart fired, while loadedmetadata, loadeddata, and canplay did not. Finally, I suspect the remote stream did not have any data so I tried to log the ready state and it was always 0.